# How to check and see if an input contains special characters in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am a high school programmer currently writing code in Python to strengthen my programming skills and am creating a basic signup page. I want my code to alert the user if their input for a username or password is invalid, but all of the answers I have seen so far are not very helpful. I have found "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" to be the most useful so far for detecting special characters such as asterisks and periods, but it seems to only work when a user uses all of the characters above instead of just the ones within the range of characters that satisfy the requirement. I will show my code below:

```
 while not chosen_user:
     chosen_user = input("""Enter the username that you would like. Please keep it between 6 and 15 
     characters. Do not use special characters such as '&', '@', or '!' in your username. Underscores are allowed.\n>""")
    if (len(chosen_user) >= 6 or len(chosen_user) <= 15) and "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" in chosen_user:
        chosen_user = True
        usernames_passwords[chosen_user] = ''
    else:
        print('Username does not meet the requirements. Please try again.')
        chosen_user = False
 while not chosen_pass:
     chosen_pass = input("""Enter a password that contains no special characters. Password must be at 
        least 6 characters.\n>""")
        if len(chosen_pass) >= 6 and "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" in chosen_pass:
            chosen_pass = True
            usernames_passwords[chosen_user] = chosen_pass
        else:
            print('Password is invalid. Please try again.')
            chosen_pass = False
```

I cannot figure out how to get a password approved while only using *some* of the characters, and I have been struggling for a while. Any help would be nice.

**Also, keep in mind that I am in high school and would prefer to keep this code as simple as possible. Imports are okay, but I would like to understand how and when to use these things for future use. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
import re #--> import regular expressions module

while not chosen_user:
    chosen_user = input("""Enter the username that you would like. Please keep it between 6 and 15
    characters. Do not use special characters such as '&', '@', or '!' in your username. Underscores are allowed.\n>""")
    if (len(chosen_user) >= 6 and len(chosen_user) <= 15) and re.search(r"^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$", chosen_user):
        chosen_user = True
        usernames_passwords[chosen_user] = ''
    else:
        print('Username does not meet the requirements. Please try again.')
        chosen_user = False

while not chosen_pass:
    chosen_pass = input("""Enter a password that contains no special characters. Password must be at 
    least 6 characters.\n>""")
    if len(chosen_pass) >= 6 and re.search(r"^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$", chosen_pass):
        chosen_pass = True
        usernames_passwords[chosen_user] = chosen_pass
    else:
        print('Password is invalid. Please try again.')
        chosen_pass = False
```

Comment: I wanted to know why you chose to use "^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$" as opposed to "^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$". I used your code for my project since it was the easiest to understand and it worked perfectly, but for future reference, I would like to know the difference between the two.

Comment: @AnonymouslyMe `*` is a quantifier which matches zero or more times.  `+` is a quantifier which matches one or more times. As the password should always contain more than one character hence i have used `+` quantifier. In this case its totally fine if you use `*` instead thats upto you.

Comment: @AnonymouslyMe I suggest you read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions) about quantifiers in regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your looping logic and also your string checking by using regular expressions:

```
import re

chosen_user = input("""Enter the ... allowed.\n>""")
while not re.match(r"^\w{6,15}$", chosen_user, flags=re.ASCII):
    chosen_user = input('Username does not meet the requirements. Please try again.')

chosen_pass = input("""Enter a password ... least 6 characters.\n>""")
while not re.match(r"^[a-zA_Z]{6,}$", chosen_pass):
    chosen_pass = input('Password is invalid. Please try again.')
```

You will find in the [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

**`"^"`**
(Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline.

**`"$"`**
Matches the end of the string [...].

**`"\w"`**
Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched.

**`"{m,n}"`**
Causes the resulting RE to match from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as many repetitions as possible. For example, a{3,5} will match from 3 to 5 'a' characters. Omitting m specifies a lower bound of zero, and omitting n specifies an infinite upper bound.

Answer (score -2):

```
 while not chosen_user:
     chosen_user = input("""Enter the username that you would like. Please keep it between 6 and 15 
     characters. Do not use special characters such as '&', '@', or '!' in your username. Underscores are allowed.\n>""")
    if (len(chosen_user) >= 6 or len(chosen_user) <= 15) and "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" in chosen_user:
        chosen_user = True
        usernames_passwords[chosen_user] = ''
    else:
        print('Username does not meet the requirements. Please try again.')
        chosen_user = False
 while not chosen_pass:
     pas = input("""Enter a password that contains no special characters. Password must be at 
        least 6 characters.\n>""")
        schar="@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]"
        if len(pas)>=6:
           for i in pas:
               if i in schar:
                   choosen_pass=True
                   break
            usernames_passwords[chosen_user] = chosen_pass
        else:
            print('Password is invalid. Please try again.')
            chosen_pass = False
```